# DatagramSocket never receives

Tags: java, networking, udp

Despite me knowing that my UDP packets are arriving as expected (via Wireshark), and having the Windows firewall turned off - my very simple Java code never receives any packets.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000 );
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buffer, buffer.length );
socket.receive( packet );
```

I have 3 network adapters on my machine, so I tried being very specific about IPs.  I tried setting the socket to look at the local address the packets were arriving on - didn't receive anything.  And I also tried connecting the socket to the remote IP the packets were being sent on - didn't receive anything.  All the while Wireshark is seeing all the 160 packets per second arriving...

My only other thought was that I'm not calculating the UDP checksum on the sending end (the UDP packets are assembled 'by hand' on an embedded system), it is just being set to 0x0000 - does `DatagramSocket` discard UDP packets without a checksum!?

---

I wrote a simple test server to aid diagnosing the problem per @Andreas' suggestion.

```
InetAddress outAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
InetAddress inAddr = InetAddress.getByName( "192.178.178.0" );

byte[] buffer = ( "Hello" ).getBytes();
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000, outAddr );
while ( true ) {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buffer, buffer.length, 
                                                inAddr, 50000 );
    socket.send( packet );

    try {
        Thread.sleep( 500 );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        // Ignore.
    }
}
```

Wireshark dutifully notes that it is receiving them all - but my client still doesn't, even when the receiving IP is explicitly set:

```
InetAddress inAddr = InetAddress.getByName( "192.178.178.0" );
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000, inAddr );
...
socket.receive( packet );
```

---

Something odd I have just noticed though, when I check which `NetworkInterface` is being used for sending and receiving, Java reports back the right one (the one 'owning' 192.178.178.0) - but Wireshark only sees my test server packets on a different network device.  Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: What are your firewall settings for this socket? I suspect wireshark can see beyond your OS firewall.

Comment: Have you considered implementing a simple UDP sender in Java to check if your packet receiving code works generally? As far as I know, UDP checksum is optional - if it is 0, it should be ignored

Comment: @PeterLawrey Windows firewall is off, and it is a direct connection to a switch in an embedded system - there is no hardware or software firewall at that end.

Comment: @Andreas I threw together a simple application that sends and receives a UDP message, and it worked - but Wireshark never saw any packets!  So I discarded it.  But you're right, making a server for my 'proper' code is definitely good testing idea.

Comment: What happens if you listen for the IP address you see the packets are being sent to.  I suspect DatagramSocket is binding to your default interface and only listening to some IP addresses, not all for that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well this is embarassing.  I turned off the Windows firewall for Private and Work networks - but it turns out Windows considered the one I actually needed to be a Public network...

It works fine now.  I considered deleting this question, but hopefully it will help some other muppet.

Comment: You should accept this answer though to show that the issue has been solved.

Comment: There's two day waiting period before it will let me.

Comment: @cmannett85 what exactly you mean by the statement "Windows considered the one I actually needed to be a Public network"?